# failed execute of devc++ program

Tags: c, codeblocks, dev-c++

I've compiled this on devc++ and it returns this message

> ERROR 193 : it isn't a win32 valid application.

I cannot figure it out where's the problem.

Is codeblocks better than devc++ for the prog in C? Because I mostly find problems with devc++ , so please tell me what's the problem and why I  can't compile this with devc++

```
/* Doubly Linked List implementation */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node  {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* head; // global variable - pointer to head node.

//Creates a new Node and returns pointer to it. 
struct Node* GetNewNode(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode
        = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

//Inserts a Node at head of doubly linked list
void InsertAtHead(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head; 
    head = newNode;
}

//Inserts a Node at tail of Doubly linked list
void InsertAtTail(int x) {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next; // Go To last Node
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
}

//Prints all the elements in linked list in forward traversal order
void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("Forward: ");
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Prints all elements in linked list in reverse traversal order. 
void ReversePrint() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    if(temp == NULL) return; // empty list, exit
    // Going to last Node
    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    // Traversing backward using prev pointer
    printf("Reverse: ");
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    /*Driver code to test the implementation*/
    head = NULL; // empty list. set head as NULL. 

    // Calling an Insert and printing list both in forward as well as reverse direction. 
    InsertAtTail(2); Print(); ReversePrint();
    InsertAtTail(4); Print(); ReversePrint();
    InsertAtHead(6); Print(); ReversePrint();
    InsertAtTail(8); Print(); ReversePrint();

}
```

Comment: What are your compiling parameters inside dev-c++?

Comment: If you don't like dev-c++, you can download and use [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fit-it%2Fhelp%2F2977003%2Fthe-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). This is a little [tutorial](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-do-Pure-C-programming-with-Visual-Studio-2017-I-want-to-relearn-C) on how to pure C programming on VS

Comment: @Simo VS is not a standard compliant C compiler. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It has a C compiler, and it comes out straight from Microsoft. Why not?

Comment: I can't find any error in that, as @Lundin pointed - that might be cause of error. The output on GCC is as expected.

Comment: By the way, the problem is probably some wrong parameters inside the compiler. But without further informations form the PO, who knows

Comment: @Simo _Because_ it comes straight from Microsoft. They don't care about following standards. In addition, MS focus on C++ and have mostly dropped support for the C mode of the compiler, which remains horribly outdated despite a few attempts to update it.

Comment: @Lundin gotcha!

Comment: @Lundin but is this opinion based?

Comment: @Simo Not an opinion but fact. A conforming C program cannot compile on VS. It can compile on gcc, clang, icc and so on.

Comment: Anyway, what do you think about the PO's error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are getting, if I understand French, is that the compiled program is not a valid Win32 application. This might simply be because you picked a Windows project, but provide `int main()` instead of `WinMain`. This should be a console application project.

If this is not the reason, I would suspect some non-programming-related cause, like having the executable running while linking, anti-virus programs causing havoc, user access rights etc etc.

DevC++ is no longer maintained and so it contains an older version of the gcc/g++ compiler. So I would strongly recommend Codeblocks instead, as it can use the latest version of the compiler. It is also a far more powerful IDE overall and since it also compiles your code cleanly, there is no reason to stick with DevC++.